# What is "spot duty" in American football?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I know "spot duty" is used in baseball to talk about spot starters, but what does this term mean in football?

> That's the kind of contract typically given to veteran backups (think Nick Bellore, who saw **spot duty** at linebacker and fullback for the Lions last year), and puts him squarely behind Wiggins in the offensive line pecking order. ([Detroit Free Press](https://www.freep.com/story/sports/nfl/lions/2018/04/06/detroit-lions-kenny-wiggins-wesley-johnson/492390002/))
>
> Tebow not thrilled with **spot duty** ([NBC Sports](https://profootballtalk.nbcsports.com/2012/11/08/tebow-not-thrilled-with-spot-duty/))

"Spot play" also appears in the same NBC article:

> I think **spot play** is fun because you’re in different roles, but at the same time it’s hard to get a feel.  Sometime even if it’s just a few plays on a drive, it gets easier.  Sometimes that’s the harder part of **spot playing**, but it is fun.  I just love playing period.

What do "spot duty" and "spot play" mean?

Comment: It pretty much means _occasional_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It pretty much means occasional. – J.R.♦